# Assigning webapp vars to html js code using jinja

Tags: javascript, jinja2

```html
            <script>
                const restrictedGuildRoles = {{ guild_roles|tojson }}
                // initialize Tagify
                var input = document.querySelector('[name=restrictedRoles]'),
                    tagify = new Tagify(input, {
                        whitelist: restrictedGuildRoles.map(({id, name}) => ({value: name, id})),
                        dropdown: {
                            position: "input",
                            enabled: 0, // always opens dropdown when input gets focus
                            searchKeys: ['title']
                        },
                    })
                const restrictedRoles = {{ find_application_data["restricted_roles"]|safe }}
                if (restrictedRoles) {
                    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(enabledRoles)) {
                        tagify.addTags(value)
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Hey guys. Currently trying to import some data from my backend flask app using Jinja. However, its resulting in some syntax errors because the JS doesn't know how to handle it.

When I use `|json` instead of `|safe` it works fine. However, if theres no data in the database, `restrictedRoles` is None, meaning it cannot convert it to json. This causes non json convert error. So I have to use `safe` so if it errors, it wont crash the whole program.

I want to steer away from using try/except, as it's not ideal.

Any idea how I can go around fixing this?